# Issue installing nuget Fody and Costura.Fody packages on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, nuget-package, fody, fody-costura

I got an error when try to add Fody and/or Costura packages

> 200/5000
>   This project refers to one or more NuGet packages that are not present on this computer. Use the NuGet package recovery tool to download them. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.

I take a [video](https://streamable.com/m31cg) to explain better

If I tried to install other packages as ClosedXML there are no issue at all

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (italian version) updated to last version and Windows 10 Pro 1803

Any ideas?

Comment: Not everyone on SO speaks Italian..

Comment: So have you followed the trouble-shooting steps in the [documentation for this error](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/nuget/Consume-Packages/Package-restore-troubleshooting)?

Comment: Yes. it didn't help. The question seems related to Fody and/or Custura because I've no issue with other nuget packages

Comment: Did you see the instructions in the [docs for the project](https://github.com/Fody/Costura), to install from the Packag Manager **console**? `PM> Install-Package Fody
PM> Install-Package Costura.Fody`? They comment that _"The Install-Package Fody is required since NuGet always defaults to the oldest, and most buggy, version of any dependency."_ and that [worked for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mieO.png), in VS2017 en/GB though.

Comment: Yes, The problem is that Fody should be installed as first package but It doesn't work. Fody and Custura.Fody can't be installed, both. 
The log is quite different https://i.postimg.cc/NMd4htrg/image.png

Comment: Solved editing the project file. The problem is about installation but there are no other issues